# Unable to enter jupyter docker at google cloud [solve]

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform

Code to create my jupyter container:

```
docker run -d -it -p 8888:8888 continuumio/miniconda3 /bin/bash -c "/opt/conda/bin/conda install jupyter -y --quiet && mkdir /opt/notebooks && /opt/conda/bin/jupyter notebook --notebook-dir=/opt/notebooks --allow-root --ip='*' --port=8888 --no-browser"
```

After allowing both port 80 and 8888 in google cloud firewall, I'm unable to access jupyter by port 8888. I had enter 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8888' in the broswer.

However, when I replace all 8888 with 80, I can access jupyter. I had enter 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' in broswer

[screenshot of my google cloud config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8JMF.jpg)

Thank you for looking. Any input will be appreciated.

Comment: I checked and your command and image works perfectly fine in my VM setup. So it is not an issue related to docker. Even your port setting seems to be fine. What do you get when you try and connect to 8888?

Comment: Omg.. Thanks for ur input, it had help me figured out why. My workplace network block the target port